# How to fix error L2029 on microsoft 16-bit linker?

Tags: assembly, linker, masm, x86-16, 16-bit

I'm trying to assemble debug.exe/com from the [MS-DOS 2.0 source code](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/tree/master/v2.0/source), at first it wasn't working but I've been changing some filenames and I've managed to get an .obj file, using link(16-bit version) there is an error (error L2029: unresolved external) on some commands, and I don't know what to do, do I need to add some libraries?

Here's the errors and commands where it fails:

```
batch
C:\Users\<my_username>\Desktop\Assembly>link16.exe

Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993.  All rights reserved.

Object Modules [.obj]: debug.obj
Run File [debug.exe]: 
List File [nul.map]:
Libraries [.lib]:
Definitions File [nul.def]:
LINK : warning L4021: no stack segment

debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'PARSERR' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'GO' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'REG' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'NAME' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'BYTEBUF' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'RELEASEPARITY' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DUMP' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'FILL' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DEFIO' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'LINEBUF' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'COMPARE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DSIZ' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'MOVE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'LOAD' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DEFDUMP' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'PARITYMES' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DISPB' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'TRACE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'TRAPPARITY' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'PERR' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'HEADSAVE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'BADVER' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DATAEND' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'ASSEM' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'LBUFSIZ' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'SPSAVE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'ENDMES' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'BACMES' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'ASMADD' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'SKIP_FILE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'PREPNAME' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'NEWEXEC' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'ZTRACE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DSSAVE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DISADD' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DWRITE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'DEBUG_FOUND' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'STACK' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'SEARCH' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'ENTER' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'QFLAG' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'INPUT' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'PARITYFLAG' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'UNASSEM' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'GETHEX' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'GETEOL' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'CSSAVE' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'CARRET' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'NOREGL' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'OUTPUT' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'USER_PROC_PDB' : unresolved external
debug.obj(DEBUGGER) : error L2029: 'IPSAVE' : unresolved external


There were 52 errors detected
```

The code, tools, and other dependencies I've used can be downloaded from [here](https://mega.nz/#!hioDTYIL!hUSrTreGZI7u--OeBDJiR24ed8SQnGiWeXyZgrkwT2s).

How can I fix these unresolved errors?

Comment: Instead of entering all the names in like that you can provide them on the command line with `link16 debug.obj,debug.exe,,,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a script to assemble MS-DOS 2.00's DEBUG. Here's the script: https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/msdos2/file/05669dfa5edd/v2.0/source/debug/makdebug.bat quoted in full:

```
@echo %DEBUG%off
masm debug debug debug;
masm debasm debasm debasm;
masm debcom1 debcom1 debcom1;
masm debcom2 debcom2 debcom2;
masm debconst debconst debconst;
masm debdata debdata debdata;
masm debmes debmes debmes;
masm debuasm debuasm debuasm;
link debug debasm debcom1 debcom2 debconst debdata debmes debuasm;
exe2bin debug
move /y debug.bin debug.com
```

In my repo I also moved all files for that into a subdirectory.

Comment: More information at http://www.bttr-software.de/forum/forum_entry.php?id=15572&page=2&category=0&order=time "Building MS-DOS 2.00's DEBUG (version 2.30)"

Comment: I couldn't use masm to build debcom2, but thanks to the links you added I downloaded debcom2.obj and finaly build debug, thanks!

Comment: How did building debcom2 fail?

Comment: I can't really tell you, I'm using DOSBox because I have a 64-bit system, and I can only see the last errors...

Answer (score 1):

The `unresolved external` linker errors are telling you that there are symbols that it can't find in the object file(s) you are processing. In your case you are only assembling `DEBUG.ASM` to `DEBUG.OBJ` and then linking to `DEBUG.EXE`. A cursory glance at the [MS-DOS 2.0 source code](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/tree/master/v2.0/source) suggests that many of the missing symbols are in `DEBDATA.ASM`, `DEBCONST.ASM`, and `DEBCOM2.ASM` (Maybe other files but those are 3 holding most of those symbols). You will need to assemble those ASM files into object files and link them together with your `DEBUG.OBJ` to produce a final `DEBUG.EXE` executable.

When linking, if you have unresolved symbols you will need to find the files that define the symbols and then somehow assemble and link them into your program.

Comment: Your solution was ok too but you missed some files, thank you too.